# Searching and downloading OpenStreetMap data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

My OpenLayers plugin is under web and not under the plugin and I can't find add OpenStreetMap  layer. I went ahead and opened *web > open layers plugin > openstreetmap* but this is the error I keep getting.

> 2018-04-10T13:40:26   1   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/RUKEVWE/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py",
>   line 100, in addLayer self._addLayerCallback(self) File
>   "C:/Users/RUKEVWE/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py",
>   line 182, in addLayer self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys) File
>   "C:/Users/RUKEVWE/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py",
>   line 231, in setMapCrs extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap,
>   QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform) QgsCsException: forward
>   transform of (-8.208501, -2.390302) PROJ.4: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84
>   +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Comment: what version of qgis are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18.16